# Calling python def's from a table in excel

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have an Excel spreadsheet with the name of columns that I want to add to my dataframe:

| Type | Column | Formula |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | Status | status(dataframe) |
| A | Present Value | p_value(dateframe) |

Using this code, I add those columns to my dataframe.

```
tbl_cols = xlsx_table(filename, sheetname='Sheet1', table='New_Columns')
tbl_cols = pd.DataFrame(tbl_cols)
tbl_cols = tbl_cols.loc[tbl_cols['Type'] == "A"]
tbl_cols = tbl_cols.loc[:, ['Column']]
New Cols = list(tbl_cols .iloc[:, 0].values)
doc[New Cols] = ""
```

After this, I added to my dataframe those "type A" columns.
Currently, I just call the functions that return the value for each of those new columns.

But I want to know if there is a way to call those functions using the [Formula] column in my spreadsheet.
So, if I want to change something, I will just update the Excel document without having to add something new to the code.

Is there a way to do this?

(All def's listed in the Excel spreadsheet are defined separately in the code. The requirement is to use Excel; I cannot use a different tool, even though it might be a better fit.)

Comment: Are you very very certain that nobody is going to inject malicious code into your spreadsheet?  If so, the super easy solution is to use `eval()`.  The less easy but more secure solution would be to have a dispatch table of valid functions.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this to call a function by its name as a string:

```
def test():
    return "this is a test function"

func = globals()["test"] #test can come from your file

func()
```